# How to rewrite this statement with JOIN, to make it faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a mySQL query, it is working, but when it comes to 1.6 million executions, it does not meet the performance I need, because of the constant re-executions of `NOT EXIST(new query)`

```
INSERT INTO `votes` (`representatives_rID`, `events_eID`, `voteResult`) 
SELECT `representatives`.`rID`,`events`.`eID`,? 
FROM `representatives`, `events` 
WHERE `events`.`eventDateTime` = ? 
AND `representatives`.`rID` = ? 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `votes` 
                WHERE `votes`.`representatives_rID` = `representatives`.`rID` 
                AND `votes`.`events_eID` = `events`.`eID`);
```

In schematic:

```
if (input one is in `representatives` AND input two is in `events` AND there is no row in `votes` that contains ( `votes`.`representatives_rID` = `representatives`.`rid` and `votes`.`events_eID` = `events`.`eID)) {
    insert a row into votes containing `eid` from `events` and `rid` from `representatives` and input three;
}
```

Is there any way of making this faster, possibly with join?

Comment: . . You should use a JOIN with a GROUP BY and a COUNT and change your "WHERE NOT EXISTS" to "WHERE nVotes = 0". I'll post the sample in a moment.

Comment: @Diego Nunes. I'm prepared to be persuaded, but that doesn't *sound* terribly orthodox or efficient! How about a good old-fashioned OUTER JOIN? or even a simple IGNORE!?!?

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know if I got the question the same way as you. I think he just wants to avoid the subquery. The "Having" on "Group By" should do it.

Comment: I didn't see that he is inserting in the same table that he is checking. Your INSERT IGNORE is perfect for this case.

Comment: Yes, I was inserting into the same table that I was checking, and IGNORE solved the problem. I only needed to modify the table structure, to make the `rid` and `eid` a primary key, instead of a custom auto-incrementing key that I was using. Way faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO votes 
(representatives_rID
,events_eID
,voteResult
) 
SELECT r.rID
     , e.eID
     , ?
  FROM representatives r 
 CROSS
  JOIN events e
    ON e.eventDateTime = ? 
   AND r.rID = ?;
```

?